# how to dismiss view in MMTransitionAnimator

Tags: ios, objective-c

MMTransitionAnimator pod file was installed. View while swiping up and down its working fine but its not dismiss view while tap on button.Please refer  this link github.com/mojun/MMTransitionAnimator.How to dismiss view while clicked on button action.can anyone help me.

Comment: How you presented your animated controller?

Comment: yes plz check this example https://github.com/mojun/MMTransitionAnimator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While presenting:

```
self.modalVC.delegate = self;
```

In ModalViewController that is presented make a delegate that:

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)closeButtonPressed;
@end

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@implementation ModalViewController 

- (void)btnCloseTapped {
   [self.delegate closeButtonPressed];
}

@end
```

Then Implement that delegate in your presenting view controller like:

```
- (void)closeButtonPressed {
    //Needs to play more..
    _animator = [[MMTransitionAnimator alloc] initWithOperationType:MMTransitionAnimatorOperationNone fromVC:_modalVC toVC:self];
    _animator.usingSpringWithDamping = 0.8f;
    _animator.interactiveType = MMTransitionAnimatorOperationDismiss;
    _containerView.alpha = 1;
    _handleBarView.y = self.view.height - _handleBarView.height;;

    [self.modalVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: can u give any example?

Comment: please see the closeButtonPressed func, though it still needs some improvemnets

Comment: Thanks for reply. Give me  full example  of this one. wait i wll check and let u know

Comment: thanks its working fine but swipe is not working after dismiss view.

Comment: after dismissing view  use below methods swipe also working fine                                                                                 
 [self modalVC];
    [self setupAnimator];